# After updating to Android Studio Arctic Fox, I cannot use any custom theme

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-plugin, android-studio-plugin, android-studio-arctic-fox

After updating to Android Studio Arctic Fox, I cannot choose any of my installed themes. Invalid cache and restart didn't help ;) Also reinstalling themes still not solving this problem.

I updated AS 4.2 to Arctic Fox using Toolbox on the stable channel. I'm on win 10.

Maybe someone has an idea how to solve this issue?

What I can choose:

[image]

What I have installed:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, so I tried installing the light theme manually. [It just shows this error.](https://i.imgur.com/kGorV8I.png) I guess we have to wait for it to be updated?

Comment: I was using canary and then beta version of AS Arctic Fox on other instances and hadn't such a problem. And cyan and purple are under the JetBrains brand.. Finger cross

Comment: Here is the Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68599712/5773037

Comment: Was fixed in **Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1**

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## Follow Simple Steps to Fix this

1. Rename the `{path-of-android-studio}/lib/gson-2.7.jar` file to `gson-2.7.jar.disabled`.
2. Restart Studio.

---

where `{path-of-android-studio}` is by default `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio` on Windows and `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents` on Mac.

---

#### The fix will be included in the next minor release of the 2020.3.1 Arctic Fox.

Found From [issue-tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194925628#comment4)

Comment: and if you are using toolbox than path is defined in Toolbox > Settings > Tools > Tools installation location

Comment: How can we edit this thing in Linux(specifically ubuntu)? As snaps are not editable in ubuntu

Comment: Arctic Fox is definitely one of the buggiest updates they have released in a while.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS it works for me and another 48+ persons.

Comment: May I know the version of Material theme you got? @NikunjParadva

Comment: Material Theme UI 5.6.0.1

Comment: Same but really not working on Arctic Fox 2020.3.1, not sure if using together with Atom Material Icon is the reason.

Comment: update arcticfox with new patch1 update on stable channel it may be helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment and the question

Answer (score 3):

The bug still persists in release **2020.3.1** as highlighted [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194925628?pli=1).

Renaming the `gson-2.7.jar` file works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is [fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194925628)
and will be included in the next minor release.

Answer (score 0):

The issue still has not been fixed in 2020.3.1 Arctic Fox :(.
For people using linux, If you have installed the flatpak version of android studio you can find the file in the below directory,

/home/void/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.google.AndroidStudio/x86_64/stable/945347e3ed941b868f366b6dc46cf294cafec69f21dbcb10d3fc4e69620315a4/files/extra/android-studio/lib

you don't have to go all the way to the end. Once you get to
/home/void/.local/share/flatpak/app/com.google.AndroidStudio

search "gson" and the right file will come up in a second.

Unfortunately for people who used snap package to install (i honestly don't why still people use snap packages) there is no way to edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue even in  **2020.3.1**, I resolved this issue by simply **deleting all the contents in `.idea`** folder from my project. And updated my project **kotlin version to 1.5.0**.

Answer (score 0):

For **Arctic Fox 2020.3.1**:

Check for new updates and update. It will be updated to **2020.3.1 Patch 1** it will solve the issue.