# Theme plugins NOT working After Update Android studio to fox 2020.3.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have Updated Android Studio to the latest version `Fox 2020.3.1` and when I opened the program I found Themes not working as it was in the previous version. I have checked the themes plugins and I found It is installed, but `they does not appear in the list of themes in Appearance & Behavior`. I have removed most of the themes and reinstalled them again, but they also did not appear and not working. So how can I fix This problem?

Comment: yes, It's not working. but you can Import themes manually.

Comment: great, and how can I import them manually?

Comment: Perfect solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68599712/5773037

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Follow Simple Steps to Fix this

1.Rename the {path-of-android-studio}/lib/gson-2.7.jar file to gson-2.7.jar.disabled.

2.Restart Studio.

Comment: It worked in my case. At first, AS did not start, and in the Task Manager, there was a background AS process, so I killed it and then it started with themes back.