# Why many Android Studio IDE themes aren't working in the new Arctic Fox version?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

I downloaded the new version of Android Studio IDE, Arctic Fox 2020.3.1. The themes that I downloaded as plugins aren't working anymore.

They aren't visible under the Appearance and if you search the theme and try to apply it, it doesn't work either.

**Does anybody know why and how to fix it?**

I've tried with *Material Atom One Theme*, *Material Theme UI Lite* and *One Dart Theme*.

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68599712/5773037