# Android Studio doesn't show any installed plugins in Theme

Tags: android-studio

I'm using the One Dark Theme for Android Studio but now I can't use it because the plugin doesn't show up in `Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance > Theme`.

[image]

As you can see, I have it installed:

[image]

I installed other plugins to see if One Dark Theme was the problem but nothing worked

[image]

I restarted the IDE, uninstalled and installed back to fix the issue but nothing worked. I even installed the ZIP file of the plugin manually but that did not work either.

This issue started to happen after I updated Android Studio to `Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 (203.7583922)`.

Comment: Here is the Solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68599712/5773037